# prevent scale in Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael, scale

Have a small issue - need help on how to prevent zooming text during resizing paper with the shapes.

Have a Raphael paper created:

...

```
this._paper = Raphael(this._inner[0],this._inner.width(),this._inner.height());
this._set = this._paper.set();
```

...

and scaling done using:

```
zoomIn: function(event, useCoords) {
        this.zoomTo(this._zoom * this.options.zoomStep, event, useCoords);

    },
    zoomOut: function(event, useCoords) {
        this.zoomTo(this._zoom / this.options.zoomStep, event, useCoords);
    },
```

...

```
this._paper.setSize(w, h);
this._paper.setViewBox(0, 0, this._mapWidth, this._mapHeight, false);
```

...

The shapes and texts are on the same paper so panning the paper makes the texts are scalled as well. Is there a way on how to prevent it?

Comment: I think you may need to post up a concise jsfiddle example or something.

Comment: Ok, fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/vqrkypp2/    (simplified for testing purposes)

Comment: This is a bit fiddly I think. A couple of options spring to mind. One would be adjusting the text size depending on the zoom (but you may need to translate it as well). The other would be overlaying 2 papers, one which isn't zoomed with the text (not tried this), but not sure if that would work with the rest of the more complex work.

Comment: Yeah - have started doing the 2nd approach some time ago. Works good on a separate page - slightly worse for a complicated project. In addition shapes need to be able to perform zooming in/out so if we have text on a separate layer there is a need of 'tracking' shape X, Y, width, height values to assign them for text. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done, for ones who are interested on how it's been achieved:

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/0ky5avg3>
```